# Angular: How to render array of objects containing array?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I render this array of objects in Angular?

```
var list = [{
    collaborators: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "test"
    }]
  },
  {
    colleagues: [{
      id: 2,
      name: "colleague2"
    }]
  }
]
```

I tried in this way

```
<div *ngFor="let el of list">
  <div *ngFor="let e of el.collaborators">
    {{e.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: yes, this doesn't work because the array name is different: `collaborators` and `colleagues`. And in `HTML` you are accessing only `collaborators`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break down your list

`list[0]` will give

```
{collaborators: [{id: 1, name: "test"}]},
```

and `list[1]` will give

```
{colleagues: [{id:2, name: "colleague2"}]}
```

Lets now loop

```html
   <div *ngFor="let e of list[0].collaborators">
     {{e.id}}
   </div>
  <div *ngFor="let e of list[1].colleagues">
     {{e.id}}
   </div>
```

We can also combine them like

```html
  <div *ngFor="let e of list">
     <ng-container *ngIf=' e.collaborators'>
        <div *ngFor='let collaborator of e.collaborators'>
            {{ collaborator.id }}
         </div>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngIf=' e.colleagues'>
        <div *ngFor='let colleague of e.colleagues'>
            {{ collaborator.id }}
         </div>
     </ng-container>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing (let e) :

```
   <div *ngFor="let e of el.collaborators">
     {{e.id}}
   </div>
```

Comment: No...it was an error of transcription. It doesn't work also with "let" declaration

Comment: Is list part of the component scope? constructor() { this.list=[...]}